# Setting object data in an Active Record pattern, before sql commit

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the Active Record design pattern in my web app, and after looking at the code in my class that handles CRUD (create, read, update and delete) on a table in the DB, i'm wondering if there's a better way to set the data.

Let's say my table has around 15 columns, and my class has 15 member variables to represent the columns. I have a form which allows a user to input data for each of those variables, and on submit, my script reads everything from _POST and _GET and compiles it into an array called $params.

Currently my class setter methods looks like this:

```
public function setData($data1, $data2, $data3,...,$dataN-1){
   $this->data1 = $data1;
   $this->data2 = $data2;
   $this->data3 = $data3;
   ...
   $this->dataN-1 = $dataN-1;
}
```

I was wondering, what the problems would be if I changed the setData argument to be an array, specifically the array containing the _POST and _GET values, so something like this

```
public function setData($data){
   $this->data1 = $data['data1'];
   $this->data2 = $data['data2'];
   $this->data3 = $data['data3'];
   ...
   $this->dataN-1 = $data['dataN-1'];
}
```

Assume that all the form element names are correct. Obviously, the time will be saved when I call the method, not having to list 15 arguments. I am going to be using prepared statements for all INSERTs and UPDATEs. Are there any other pitfalls that I should be aware of doing this?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use an array too for $this->data[] in your class?

You could this way use a foreach and could maintain/automatize it more easily, fetching data or setting it in your DB.

EDIT : this way you fill your array

in your class :

```
private $data = array(
   'db_column_name_1' => null,
   'db_column_name_2' => null,
   'db_column_name_3' => null,
   ...
   'db_column_name_n' => null
);

public function setData($data){
   foreach ( $this->data as $key => $value )
     $this->data[$key] =  $data[$key] ;
}
```

Symmetrically you could as easily make the right INSERT/UPDATE query

Comment: Funny you should mention that, because I was going to ask exactly the same thing in my next SO post :) Any comments on this would be helpful!

Comment: Make a private array in your class, like array ( 'your_column1' => null, 'your_column2' => null ...); then, you can foreach this class array, and update your data. Then, to insert it in your DB, you can re-foreach this array (with this time new data fetched) and make your UPDATE/INSERT query, by having the name of your columns as keys of the array. It is a pleasure then to maintain or reuse :)